# Pandas dataframe to table with subheaders (Latex or Image)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
|Label      |Metric A |Metric B  |Category |
--------------------------------------------
|model 1    |0.9      |0.7       |Train    |
|model 2    |0.87     |0.8       |Train    |
|model 1    |0.78     |0.6       |Val      |
|model 2    |0.6      |0.66      |Val      |
```

and I need to convert it in some form to something like this:

```
|         |Metric A    |Metric B     |
-------------------------------------
|         |Train|Val   |Train |Val   |
--------------------------------------
|Model 1  |     |      |      |      |
|Model 2  |     |      |      |      |
```

(I hope you get what I mean :D)
Is it even possible to convert pd dataframes into such a format?

It is in a scientific context, so I need to have it in latex (I know there is the .to_latex() function, but I dont know how to convert this dataframe in the wanted shape) or I can export it as an image so I can insert it.
(I am also a little bit familiar with R, in case there is a solution in R)
Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Label','Category']).unstack()
```

Or if possible duplicated `Label, Category` values is possible use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregation, e.g. `mean`:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Label',columns='Category', aggfunc='mean')
```

---

```
print (df1)
         Metric A       Metric B      
Category    Train   Val    Train   Val
Label                                 
model 1      0.90  0.78      0.7  0.60
model 2      0.87  0.60      0.8  0.66


print (df1.to_latex())
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Metric A} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Metric B} \\
Category &    Train &   Val &    Train &   Val \\
Label   &          &       &          &       \\
\midrule
model 1 &     0.90 &  0.78 &      0.7 &  0.60 \\
model 2 &     0.87 &  0.60 &      0.8 &  0.66 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```